# Convert a REST webrequest from Python to Java

Tags: java, python

I have a currently working program in Python and I am trying to convert it to Java.

```
webCmd = "http://192.168.1.xxx/rest/nodes/21 F1 DD 1/ST"
r = requests.get(webCmd, timeout=(0.1,2), auth=('username', 'password'))
```

I am new to Java and my code fails.

```
String authString = "username" + ":" + "password";
String encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authString.getBytes());
String authHeader = "Basic " + encodedAuth;

webCmd = "http://192.168.1.xxx/rest/nodes/21 F1 DD 1/ST";

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(webCmd).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", authHeader);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

If I run the above code, I get a 404 error. If I paste the webCmd in the browser, it prompts me for username, password and responds with the correct xml output. If I comment out the setRequestProperty line, then the response is 401 as expected.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try send the same requests with username&pass encoded via some program like Postman?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, but maybe Python is taking care of encoding those spaces in the URL path, while Java isn't? Try it again with the spaces replaced with either `+` or `%20`, maybe... (Edit: Checked docs, and they mention this, so upgrading to answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Specifically

> The URL class does not itself encode or decode any URL components according to the escaping mechanism defined in RFC2396. It is the responsibility of the caller to encode any fields, which need to be escaped prior to calling URL, and also to decode any escaped fields, that are returned from URL. Furthermore, because URL has no knowledge of URL escaping, it does not recognise equivalence between the encoded or decoded form of the same URL. For example, the two URLs:
>
> `http://foo.com/hello world/` and `http://foo.com/hello%20world`
>
> would be considered not equal to each other.

Your URL contains spaces, so you need to encode them explicitly. I guess Python does that automatically.

Comment: I guess that Python and my Chrome browser does that for me. Adding them fixed the problem. Thanks.